# Button should be disabled when wrong numbers are entered

Tags: jquery

I am having some list of numbers in a div. The div gets number from a text field. Each number has unique ID. I am having a search field. Where search field is used to search number in the div. If i search wrong numbers it should show "NO Results found". And My ISSUE IS: I am having a Clear Search Button and a Search Button. The Clear Search should be enabled only when the correct numbers are searched, rest of the time clear search button should remain disabled.  I've been trying for this functionality for past 3 days.

Here is my code:

```
$("#wmclrsrch").attr("disabled", "disabled");  //#wmclrsrch is a Clear Search Button
function fieldDisable() {
    $('#search_number').keyup(function() {         //#search_number is Search field
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $("#wmclrsrch").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#wmclrsrch").attr("enabled", "enabled");
        } else {
            $("#wmclrsrch").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}
fieldDisable();
$('#wmsearch').after(function() {         //'#wmsearch is a Search Button
    if($(this).val() != '') {
        $("#wmclrsrch").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#wmclrsrch").attr("enabled", "enabled");
    } else {
        $("#wmclrsrch").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

NOTE: My Search Function is working good. Kindly tell me how to disable button when wrong numbers are entered.

Comment: 1. could you make a minimal example on jsfiddle?
2. there is no enabled attribute in html, only disabled or nothing

Answer (score 1):

The way you are enabling and disabling the button isn't quite right. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/uvQGZ/) jsfiddle shows the way that it should be handled.

```
if($(this).val() != ''){
    $('#wmclrsrch').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('#wmclrsrch').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $('#search_number').val();
if(num.indexOf("YOUR DIV HTML STRING")>-1){
// enable button
}else{
// disable button
}
```